# Development platform for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am new in iPhone application development and currently working on .net (C#).

Please suggest the development platform to create iPhone application so I can adopt very soon.

Which is best among these:

1. Xcode
2. Unity using script language c#
3. tersus

Or any other tool that is not on the list.

Is it possible to develop iPhone application using .NET framework? I'm not sure; I think not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official SDK is free but not open-source.  All the tools necessary to build iPhone apps are free.  HOWEVER you cannot put your apps on an iPhone or iPod Touch device without paying the $99 for the developer license.  You can run the apps you build on the iPhone Simulator, which is an application that runs on your Mac.  It looks and behaves pretty much like a real iPhone, minus a few obvious things (no GPS, no camera).

Go to http://developer.apple.com/iphone/ to get started.

Comment: Need to add that the iPhone Simulator uses the Cocoa APIs rather than the Cocoa Touch APIs that are run on the iPhone. There's a pretty big difference as you can call things in the simulator which are not avaliable on the iPhone/iPod Touch.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible develop application for iPhone on Windows platform. You need official SDK and it's only for Mac OS X.

Look to http://developer.apple.com/iphone/

Comment: thanks. well i have mac OS and want to know is this official SDK is free or open source??
can you plz suggest for which one ihave to go...

Answer (score 4):

XCode is the only development environment for iPhone and Objective C is the language it uses for this. You cannot use the .NET framework to build an iPhone app.

The SDK is free to download but you will need register (for free) with apple to get the SDK and all it initially lets you do is build and run apps in a software simulator environment; to put apps on a physical phone you need to buy a license (for $99) and go through a rather convoluted process to set up signing certificates.

The SDK and a variety of sample code and tutorials are all at the Apple iPhone developer site http://developer.apple.com/iphone/.

Comment: glenra,
    Why would you say you can't use C#?  Doesn't Novell's Mono let you do that?  What about "Unity" as the question lists.

It is true, however, that you need a Mac and the SDK.

Creating a native iPhone app does use the SDK and XCode, but some environments use other languages and output an XCode project which you then compile to create the final iPhone app.  You don't actually have to use XCode to write code -- just is as the final compile step.

Answer (score 0):

Learn Obj-C . If you don't have mac then buy one.

Answer (score 0):

Unity looks very promising, but it's cost prohibitive for an indy programmer. I looked at this last week and for me to get the package I needed I'd have to drop down almost $3,000. You'd still have to use XCode to compile your app though.

Comment: Cheaper to buy a mac mini, or most any mac for that matter, at 3k.

Comment: there's a free version of Unity now, but you still need a Mac.

The cost of a Mac should really not be any issue.  If someone really can't spend the money on a Mac, you can shop around and get a slightly older Mac Mini or MacBook for pocket change.